# Simplifying 5-var Boolean SOP Expression using the Laws and Properties

Tags: math, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I have this question that is messing me up because I am not getting that where should I start, which terms should I pick at the beginning? Because this confusing expression does not even let me take the common as it makes no sense. Also, it does not even let me remove compliments (using the Laws) as it also does not make any sense. Please help me in this, at least just guide me what should I do? From where should I start? I would be really grateful.

The Explanation of Symbols I used to write the expression:

! : NOT Gate

+ : OR Gate

. (dot) : AND Gate

**Boolean Expression:**

*A.!B.E + !(B.C).D.!E + !(C.D).E+!A.D.!E + A.!(C.D).E + A.E + A.B.!E + !(A.C) + B.C.!D*

I have used an online expression simplifier and that gave me the following answer:

*!A + B + !C + D + E*

But how the above long expression has been simplified in this short one? I know the Laws and Properties but I am not getting that how should I start simplifying the long one? Which terms should I see first? Kindly anyone please help me.

Comment: Must you use "the laws and properties"? In this case it would be much easier to build a truth table, which would have just 32 rows. If your final expression is correct, the table ends in all Trues with just one exception. It is trivial to build an equivalent expression from that.

Comment: Yes @RoryDaulton, I must have to write all the steps of simplification to simplify this long expression. Well, BTW can you tell me how should I make the Truth Table? and for which expression? and what would be the inputs to the variables? How would the simplified expression be generated from that Truth Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is a direct answer to your comment, and a side-ways answer to your main question. In short, use a different method to get the desired simplified expression.)

You have a complicated expression, but one that uses only 5 logical variables. In this problem it would be much easier to build a truth table, which would have just 2^5 = 32 rows. You could look at the results and use those to build a simplified, equivalent expression. This does not use "the laws and properties" that your original question requires, but it is a standard technique to simplify Boolean expressions.

You should have learned how to build a truth table in just about any Discrete Mathematics class. In short, you make a table where each element in each row is a `T` for `True` or `F` for `False`. The rows contain all possible combinations of Ts and Fs. For 5 variables this would use 2^5 = 32 rows. For each row, you assign the first value to A, the second to B, etc. You then evaluate the expression for those values and write the result at the end of the line.

This can be done by hand, but your expression is complicated enough that we could avoid that. Here is a Python 3 script that prints the desired table. Note that Python has the `product()` function which simplifies getting all possible combinations of Ts and Fs. This script used `B[]` to convert a Boolean value to a single character `T` or `F`.

```
from itertools import product

"""Make a truth table for the Boolean expression
    A.!B.E + !(B.C).D.!E + !(C.D).E+!A.D.!E + A.!(C.D).E + A.E + A.B.!E + !(A.C) + B.C.!D
"""
B = ('F', 'T')
print('A B C D E : Result')
print('- - - - - : ------')
for a, b, c, d, e in product((True, False), repeat=5):
    print(B[a], B[b], B[c], B[d], B[e], end=' : ')
    print(B[
            (a and not b and e)
            or (not (b and c) and d and not e)
            or (not (c and d) and e)
            or (not a and d and not e)
            or (a and not (c and d) and e)
            or (a and e)
            or (a and b and not e)
            or (not (a and c))
            or (b and c and not d)
    ])
```

Here are the results:

```
A B C D E : Result
- - - - - : ------
T T T T T : T
T T T T F : T
T T T F T : T
T T T F F : T
T T F T T : T
T T F T F : T
T T F F T : T
T T F F F : T
T F T T T : T
T F T T F : T
T F T F T : T
T F T F F : F
T F F T T : T
T F F T F : T
T F F F T : T
T F F F F : T
F T T T T : T
F T T T F : T
F T T F T : T
F T T F F : T
F T F T T : T
F T F T F : T
F T F F T : T
F T F F F : T
F F T T T : T
F F T T F : T
F F T F T : T
F F T F F : T
F F F T T : T
F F F T F : T
F F F F T : T
F F F F F : T
```

We see that the result is always `T` except for the single line `T F T F F`. This means your expression is true unless A is True, B is False, C is True, and D and E are False. So we can simplify your expression (using your notation) to

```
!(A.!B.C.!D.!E)
```

A simple use of DeMorgan's laws changes this to normal form:

```
!A + B + !C + D + E
```

which is what you wanted.

Comment: thank you so much, sir for the nice explanation in simple words. Yeah, I know how to make Truth tables as I have studied Discrete Mathematics course and got 90%+ with A+ grade But this subject Digital Electronics, I am new and did not know how to solve this question. Thanks a lot for the nice explanation. I am currently studying C++ so I do not know anything about Python, but looking at the code it made sense to me as I am already almost fluent in C++. I have one more question. How would we represent this simplified expression (i.e. `!A + B + !C + D + E`) in sum of min-terms?

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar: I do not know what "min-terms" are. I studied mathematics, not Digital Electronics, and the terms may differ. The final expression is in disjunctive normal form--is that the same thing?

Comment: the min-terms of any Boolean Expression can be extracted from it's Truth Table, I am going to use `{0, 1}` instead of `{T, F}` so, in `{0, 1}` Truth Table, The results that show `1`, the variables in the row corresponding to those results are known as min-terms of the expression.

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar: I do not understand that explanation of "min-terms." Could you give a link to a full explanation?

Comment: here is the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form#Minterms you can read about mi-terms here.

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar: If I understand "min-terms" correctly, you need one for each row of the truth table that results in `T`. That means 31 min-terms in your expression. The negation of your expression is easy, using just one min-term, and is in the next-to-last expression in my answer.